# Spring filed injection into Spring TestExecutionListeners not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

How can I use Spring injection about int field(About random port) into a TestExecutionListener class I wrote extending AbstractTestExecutionListener?

I make this

```
public class IntegrationHelper extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(final TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        RestAssured.port = port;
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);

        List<String> truncateAllTablesQuery = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';') AS q FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'chatUniv'", String.class);
        truncateAllTables(jdbcTemplate, truncateAllTablesQuery);
    }

    private void truncateAllTables(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, final List<String> truncateAllTablesQuery) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");

        for (String truncateQuery : truncateAllTablesQuery) {
            jdbcTemplate.execute(truncateQuery);
        }

        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
    }
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {IntegrationHelper.class}, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

```
@IntegrationTest
public class AuthControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @DisplayName("회원가입을 한다.")
    @Test
    void register_member() {
        // given
        MemberCreateRequest memberCreateRequest = new MemberCreateRequest("a@a.com", "1234");

        // when
        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(memberCreateRequest)
                .when()
                .post("/api/auth/sign-up");

        // then
        response.then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
    }
}
```

Error message is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port must be greater than 0
```

I want to delete duplication code. So I try to move to annotation.
but random port doesn't insert in test code

Help me please..

I want to delete duplication code. So I try to move to annotation. but random port doesn't insert in test code

Answer (score 0):

It is because `AbstractTestExecutionListener` is not a Spring Bean. So if you expect to be injected by field injection, it wouldn't work.

But you can extract a port from the `TestContext` which is injected in the method.

`@Value("${local.server.port}")` is exactly the same with `@LocalServerPort`.

```java
@Override
public void afterTestMethod(final TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    Environment environment = testContext.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
    int port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port", Integer.class);
    RestAssured.port = port;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);

    List<String> truncateAllTablesQuery = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';') AS q FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'chatUniv'", String.class);
    truncateAllTables(jdbcTemplate, truncateAllTablesQuery);
}
```